# Best way to combine two CSS rules

Tags: css

I'm trying to combine the 2 blocks of codes shown below but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how best to do it?

Separate:

```
#rack #main #intro #nav-bar ul li:nth-of-type(8):hover {
    background-position: -290px -470px;
}
#rack #main #intro #nav-bar ul li.current-menu-item:nth-of-type(8) {
    background-position: -290px -470px;
}
```

Combined:

```
#rack #main #intro #nav-bar ul li:nth-of-type(8):hover,
#rack #main #intro #nav-bar ul li.current-menu-item:nth-of-type(8) {
    background-position: -290px -470px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any particular reason why it shouldn't work; btw, you can remove `#rack #main #intro` from the selectors.

Comment: Do they work fine separately?

Comment: Can you add your HTML code here to see, that could be helpful to us.

Comment: They work fine separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work but I didn't know why this is not working, I think **`li`** has a class so we have to define it first like this:

```
#rack #main #intro #nav-bar ul li.current-menu-item:nth-of-type(8),
#rack #main #intro #nav-bar ul li:nth-of-type(8):hover {
    background-position: -290px -470px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to combine 2 css styles, put a comma between them. If you can post your code I can take a look and see what might be causing the issue.